# How to make some methods from superclass not avaliable in child class

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Lets say I have a class

```
public class Base {}
```

and a child class

```
public class Derived extends Base {

    public void Foo(Object i){
        System.out.println("derived - object");
    }
}
```

and main class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Derived d = new Derived();
        int i = 5;
        d.Foo(i);
    }
}
```

In console we will see 
**derived - object**

Some time later I want to modify my superclass like this :

```
public class Base {

    public void Foo(int i) {
        System.out.println("base - int");
    }
}
```

Now if I run my programm I will see:

```
base - int
```

So can I make a method in superclass not avaliable in my child class? 
In result I want to see **derived - object**.

I see some don't understand what I want so I'll try to explain:

I want to modify only superclass and I don't want to modify my child class.. for example if I will make jar with my superclass and jar with my childs. I don't want to change all jars.. I want to add method into superclass and make it avaliable for superclass.. 
And such code

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Derived d = new Derived();
        int i = 5;
        d.Foo(i);
        Base b = new Base();
        b.Foo(i);
    }
}
```

give me

**derived - object**
    base - int

Comment: I know that c++ and c# have somy features that help to resolve such problem, but I do not know how make it in java

Comment: You might want to have a look at this post: [SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589146/overload-and-hide-methods-in-java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589146/overload-and-hide-methods-in-java

Comment: Using `@Override` annotation might also help so you know during compile time that you are actually overriding a base method.

Comment: Now you try to struggle against overriding/overloading, inheritance and boxing/unboxing. Generally this is a bad idea. You can try to discover Java language specification for complete understanding how compilator make decision about what exact method it should use. Maybe you can solve your problem somehow, but if you do it your API will be very complicated for understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use following signature for `Foo` method in base class:

```
public void Foo(Object i) {
    System.out.println("base - int");
}
```

This way you can override method `Foo` from base class. Now you do not override this method but overload it instead.

If you want to use `public void Foo(int i)` signature in your base class then you can define `Foo` method in base class as `private`.

**PS:** I hope that I've understood you.

Comment: but if I make it private I can not write like this                  Base base = new Base; base.foo(5);

Comment: if you want to always be able to override you should use this : public void Foo(Object... i) it shall capture everything

Comment: @Aleksei if a child can't access at compile time I can't see any way to make external classes access it. You want to block close scope while allowing larger scope. This can only be done by overriding the method and throwing an exception for accessviolation or something

Answer (score 2):

- **private** members are limited to the class scope.
- *default* (no keyword for this one) are limited to other members of the same package.
- **protected** are limited to hierarchy.
- **public** are not limited.

So if you don't want your child class to access a member of the superclass (member means methods, enum, variables ...) you should declare your foo like this :

```
public class Base {

    private void Foo(int i) {
        System.out.println("base - int");
    }
}
```

Edit from my comment :
if you dont want child class to access a parent's member at compile time I can't see any way to still allow external classes to access it.
You want to block access from close scope while allowing broader scope. This can only be done by overriding the method and throwing an exception for accessviolation or something which is not at compile time but at runtime. Although you could make it work with a custom annotations but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a method final, which means, that the child class cannot override it.

If you do not do that and the child class overrides the method, you cannot call the super classes method from your main.

A Convention note: Please use lowercase method names in java.

Comment: when I make my foo method final in superclass and run the programm I see "base - int". So I think that my child class overrides the method((

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.abc;


public class TestParentChild {

    public static void main(String[] asd) {
        Base b = new ChildB();
        b.foo(5);
    }
}

class Base {
    public void foo(int i) {
        System.out.println("derived - int");
    }

}

class ChildB extends Base {
    public void foo(int i) {
        System.out.println("derived - object");
    }
}
```

This might help you

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `@Override` annotation in Java. When a method is overridden in the subclass, the subclass method takes precedence over the superclass method for instances of the subclass.

```java
public class Base {
    public void Foo(Object i) {
        System.out.println("base - object");
    }
}

public class Derived extends Base {
    @Override
    public void Foo(Object i) {
        System.out.println("derived - object");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Derived d = new Derived();
        int i = 5;
        d.Foo(i); // Output: derived - object
        Base b = new Base();
        b.Foo(i); // Output: base - object
    }
}
```

the `Foo(Object i)` method is defined in the `Base` class. The `Derived` class overrides this method using the `@Override` annotation, and its implementation will be used when the `Foo` method is called on an instance of `Derived`.

When you run the `Main` class, the output will be:

```
derived - object
base - object
```

The first call to `d.Foo(i)` invokes the overridden method in the `Derived` class because `d` is an instance of `Derived`. The second call to `b.Foo(i)` invokes the method in the `Base` class because `b` is an instance of `Base`.

By using the `@Override` annotation, you ensure that the subclass method takes precedence over the superclass method for instances of the subclass, even if you add or modify methods in the superclass later. This way, you don't need to modify the child class or the JAR files containing the child class.

Comment: The `@Override` [annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html) is an instruction to the compiler. A method does not require the `@Override` annotation. An overridden method will take precedence regardless of whether the `@Override` annotation is present or not. Hence I would say that your answer is misleading. Nonetheless, as per my understanding of how this website works, misleading answers are still considered to be valid answers. Hence, rather than flagging your answer, I am writing this comment.